# Add payload and its signature in url base64 encoded and then decode it

Tags: python, url, rsa, signature

Below you will find my code of sender and receiver they are signing the message successfully and it works

## The Problem

How can I put the bytes into an url and pass the value of the payload into a GET request with the signature together encoded in base64
Something like

```
encoded_var = b64encode(payload.encode()+signature).decode('ACII')
url = "https://example.com/action?variable="+encoded_var
```

And then verify them in the receiver that the var is signed from the sender, It is a demo for transactions but I still cant get it! Any help is apreciated

```
import time
import datetime
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
def sender():
    my_url = 'https://example.com/action?variable='
    payload = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    print(payload)
    with open('mykey.pem', 'rb') as f:
        private_key = RSA.importKey(f.read(), passphrase='')
    print(private_key.can_sign())

    signature = sign(payload.encode(),private_key)

    full_message = b64encode(payload.encode()+signature)
    receiver(full_message)



def receiver(full_message ):
    message_decoded = b64decode(full_message)
    payload = message_decoded[:14].decode()
    #since i know that the lenght of the message is 14
    signature = message_decoded[-128:]
    #and I know that the signature is 128 bytes


    with open("mykey.pub", 'rb') as f:
        public_key = RSA.importKey(f.read(),passphrase='')

    print('VERIF', verify(payload.encode(), signature,public_key))

    return False





def sign(message, priv_key):
    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(priv_key)
    digest = SHA.new()
    digest.update(message)
    return signer.sign(digest)



def verify(message, signature, pub_key):
    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(pub_key)
    digest = SHA.new()
    digest.update(message)
    return signer.verify(digest, signature)


sender()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PS: I still wonder if it is url safe though with the '/' and '+' in the encoded strings

Okay Posting the answer for my problem here:
So full message is in bytes, if i decode the full message in ASCII

```
 full_message = b64encode(payload.encode()+signature)
 print(full_message)
```

returns bytes

> b'MjAxODExMjgxNjAyMTmsNkL1RwldzchBWFN5hJKr8CZu6sdOtqRloZlmVWnIi7NC6qZrmalls4up8rGdZ2FHGXIvvRtU7M5m+x7a/D48qQRCU9mw9tor9E/TkNvwAmEKmsWaiwTONd78Fgtmu7Ws7qBLBFrnA3wnUM2E+2HB6RrDe3WrlBWy39A+oRctuw=='

```
full_message = b64encode(payload.encode()+signature).decode('ASCII')
print(full_message)
```

returns string which can be attached to the url

> MjAxODExMjgxNjAxMzMdxIw7ipGAUSdnQt4mpDOdoVH5uiInkP8MM+cNFC3oapRtytv3k5ecLjB4w/kx8gs73Al+6T7/NbXyJbT+F+XYIz7DXSy4Mav2/aB9/sGZKU8Ef+Q7Z8+FJTFn0BaaGFoSyaamLx00gncHtVqPgFjvS3gAmFAdiBTQmoSNI6gmrA==

then in the `receiver`

```
def receiver(full_message ):
    #if I b64decode the whole message and then decode the payload 
    #returns true :)
   
    message_decoded = b64decode(full_message)
    payload = message_decoded[:14].decode()

    signature = message_decoded[-128:]


    ...
```